# How to set Native Microsoft compiler for VS 2003 if Intel Compiler is default compiler?

Tags: c++, ide, visual-c++

I am using a development environment with VS 2003 as IDE and Intel compiler as default compiler. I have to set Microsoft default compiler for compilation of my project. As I could not find where to set the  compiler in VS 2003.

Thanks
Anil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set the compiler explicitly, VS simply runs cl.exe.  Windows tries to find a file named cl.exe to start, it searches the directories listed in the PATH environment variable.  You *do* explicitly set which directories are in the PATH.

Not sure about VS2003, 2005 and up uses Tools + Options, Projects and Solutions, VC++ Directories, Executable files.  Remove the Intel compiler directory from that list.

Comment: VS tries to find cl.exe from PATH environment variable. 

The PATH environment variable on system is following: 

%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;C:\CCCS\BIN;c:\emacs\bin;C:\MKSNT;%VS%\COMMON\TOOLS\WINNT;%VS%\COMMON\MSDEV98\BIN;%VS%\COMMON\TOOLS;%VS%\VC98\BIN;c:\PROGRAM FILES\COMMON FILES\INTEL\SHARED FILES\IA32\BIN;%INTEL%\ICID;%INTEL%\EDB;%INTEL%\ISELECT\BIN6;%INTEL%\COMPILER60\IA32\BIN;%INTEL%\EDB70;%INTEL%\COMPILER70\IA32\BIN;%INTEL_COMPILER80%\IA32\BIN;%INTEL_SHARED%\IA32\BIN;%INTEL%\CPP\IDB73\BIN;%INTEL%\cpp\idb80\bin
I guess removing Intel Spec path will help :). Let me try it.

Comment: Only Intel compiler is hown in directory from the list, so can't remove it. This first thing I tried was this .. no luck :)

Comment: Well, it is splattered all over your path.  Three different versions no less.  Not the point though, VS creates its own PATH before running cl.exe

Comment: ok, I got it now.. I have manually overridden the path of Intel Compiler - executable,library and include option with that of VS 2003 Native.

Thanks nobugz